# React js usando leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

Cuando cambio las coordenadas para centrar el mapa o sea modifico el estado de mi componente el vuelve a renderizar el componente y esta vez tiene que centrar el mapa con las nuevas coordenas pero no lo hace

Comment: sin código es imposible saber tu problema, agrégalo, lo mínimo para que los demás entiendan cuál es tu inconveniente